# Loading Flash in a Webview, I'm lost

Tags: java, android, flash, webview

I'm trying to load this particular site : http://www.4maktoob.com/

in an android webview, but all I get is a Blank page. Here is my code :

```
final WebView myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webViewx1);
        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.4maktoob.com/");
```

Comment: What API are you using to run flash in webview? Use latest API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You need Adobe Flash installed on the device in order to load this website. It won't load in the WebView unless you have that installed.

2 - If you have Adobe Flash installed, you need to enable it in the WebView as follows (**NOTE: Adobe Flash support has been completely disabled in WebView for Android 4.4 and up**):

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON); //this is deprecated in API 19
```

This will allow the Flash plugin to load in the WebView. However, flash is pretty buggy and isn't guaranteed to work on higher API levels. I've found Flash doesn't work very well on 4.2 or 4.3.